# Quarkus use config property in annotation numeric parameter

Tags: annotations, quarkus

I am looking how to insert a config param from yaml file in Quarkus to a numeric double[] parameter in a Timed annotation in Quarkus like the percentile parameter

```
@Timed(value = "some_metric", percentiles = {0.90, 0.95})
```

something like

```
@Timed(value = "some_metric", percentiles = "${percentile.default.setting}")
```

but is obviously not accepted as percentile is not a string parameter

Any way how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom `MeterFilter` solves this problem.

The following class can override `percentiles` values by application configuration.

Custom percentiles can be configured as `metrics.[metric-name].percentiles` like:

```yaml
my-metrics:
  second_metric:
    percentiles:
      - 0.50
      - 0.60
      - 0.90
```

```java
@Singleton
public class CustomMeterFilter {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static final Class<double[]> configClass = (Class<double[]>) Array.newInstance(double.class, 0).getClass();

    @Produces
    @Singleton
    public MeterFilter customPercentiles() {
        return new MeterFilter() {
            @Override
            public DistributionStatisticConfig configure(Meter.Id id, DistributionStatisticConfig config) {
                return ConfigProvider.getConfig()
                        .getOptionalValue(String.format("my-metrics.%s.percentiles", id.getName()), configClass)
                        .map(percentiles -> DistributionStatisticConfig.builder()
                                .percentiles(percentiles)
                                .build()
                                .merge(config))
                        .orElse(config);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

More options available in [official documentation](https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/concepts/meter-filters.html)